# Merging the rows of two tables

Tags: mysql

i have two tables which i want to merge their rows based on a field. i will appreciate simple sql code for this task. for e.g.
table1. called: balances

```
PubID | Year | StudID |DrAmt| CrAmt| Desc|
------------------------------------------
12    | 2012 | OK1    | 100 | 0    | Bal c/f
11    | 2012 | OK2    | 250 | 0    | Bal c/f
10    | 2012 | OK3    | 0   | 50   | Bal c/f
12    | 2012 | OK4    | 10  | 0    | Bal c/f
```

table2. called: balances_detail

```
PubID | Items      | DrAmt | CrAmt|
-----------------------------------
12    | Stationary | 10    | 0
12    | Pendrive   | 30    | 0
12    | Utility    | 40    | 0
11    | Stationary | 5     | 0
11    | Pendrive   | 30    | 0
11    | Utility    | 10    | 0
```

and so on. 

i now want a result like this table. this table contains studID and its bal c/f as well as the balances_detail respectively to each PubID. i just need one DrAmt column and one CrAmt column which will contain the rows from the two tables and the Desc column as well.:

```
PubID | Year | StudID |DrAmt| CrAmt| Desc|
------------------------------------------
12    | 2012 | OK1    | 100 | 0    | Bal c/f
12    | 2012 | OK1    | 10  | 0    | Stationary
12    | 2012 | OK1    | 30  | 0    | Pendrive
12    | 2012 | OK1    | 40  | 0    | Utility
11    | 2012 | OK2    | 250 | 0    | Bal c/f
11    | 2012 | OK2    | 5   | 0    | Stationary
11    | 2012 | OK2    | 30  | 0    | Pendrive 
11    | 2012 | OK2    | 10  | 0    | Utility
```

Comment: please show your attempt.

Comment: @Mitch, my attempt couldn't yield any results, the challenge was with the the DrAmt and CrAmt from the two tables. i just need one DrAmt column and one CrAmt column which will contain the rows from the two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
    SELECT b.PubID, a.Year, a.StudID, b.DrAmt, b.CrAmt, b.Items AS Description 
    FROM Table2 b
    JOIN Table1 a ON a.PubID=b.PubID
    UNION
    SELECT a.PubID, a.Year, a.StudID, a.DrAmt, a.CrAmt, a.Description
    FROM Table1 a
    ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you can not merge these two tables because the resultant table have two column :

```
StudID
Desc
```

Which is not part of `balances_detail` table. If these two columns are part of `balances_detail` table then you can use [Union](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) keyword in sql statement which have a constraint:

> Notice that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same
>   number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types.
>   Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.

Please check out this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) to read about 'Union' keyword